# Is findById faster than findOne({userId: userId})?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema set up like:

```
employment = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users"
  }
  ...
})
```

Right now I am querying for a user's employment by searching the employment collection for their userId. Would it be faster to save the employmentId reference in the user model and findById? or is the difference insignificant?

Any help is appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reding the documentation we have are the same from performance perspective:
Definition of **findById**:

`` /**
 * Finds a single document by its _id field. `findById(id)` is almost*
 * equivalent to `findOne({ _id: id })`. If you want to query by a document's
 * `_id`, use `findById()` instead of `findOne()`.
 *
 * The `id` is cast based on the Schema before sending the command.
 *
 * This function triggers the following middleware.
 *
 * - `findOne()`
 *
 * \* Except for how it treats `undefined`. If you use `findOne()`, you'll see
 * that `findOne(undefined)` and `findOne({ _id: undefined })` are equivalent
 * to `findOne({})` and return arbitrary documents. However, mongoose
 * translates `findById(undefined)` into `findOne({ _id: null })`. ``

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but I am more wondering what the performance difference is between querying for and _id vs a unique field that type is an ObjectId but isn't the id of the object in mongo

Comment: ah, oki, then, you should think about create an index for that field if you are planning the collection too much. Creating an index will increase the performance at same way as for _id.